# download excel with ajax without refresh page

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to implement this in my project https://phpzag.com/demo/export_data_to_csv_using_php_mysql/
and it works great, but I want to do a simple ajax request to download without reloading the page.

I tried with this code but doesn't work:

```
    $("#export-emails").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: emails_export,
                        complete: function(res){
                            var path = res.responseJSON.path;
                            location.href= path;
                    }
                })
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant portions of the php code, generating csv file

Comment: **Do not follow phpzag.com tutorials!** They are advocating bad programming practices and their code samples are full of security problems. Please learn about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) first.

Answer (score 1):

You can force download file like this:

```
complete: function (res) {
  var path = res.responseJSON.path;
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = path;
  link.download = 'download';
  link.target = '_blank';
  link.click();
}
```